# Generate Hex color code randomly

Tags: php, background-color

I need to set "random" background color of page on fly. Is there any php function to generate Hex color code or snippet which can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no PHP built-in function

```
$rand = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$color = '#'.$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)];
```

Then echo out the $color value anywhere you need it.

Comment: Perfect, just as I needed

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
     <?php


         /**
         * Get random color hex value
         *
         * @param  int $max_r Maximum value for the red color
         * @param  int $max_g Maximum value for the green color
         * @param  int $max_b Maximum value for the blue color
         * @return string
         */

       echo getRandomColorHex();

       function getRandomColorHex($max_r = 255, $max_g = 255, $max_b = 255)
       {
          // ensure that values are in the range between 0 and 255
          $max_r = max(0, min($max_r, 255));
          $max_g = max(0, min($max_g, 255));
          $max_b = max(0, min($max_b, 255));

          // generate and return the random color
          return str_pad(dechex(rand(0, $max_r)), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) .
                 str_pad(dechex(rand(0, $max_g)), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) .
                 str_pad(dechex(rand(0, $max_b)), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sprintf('%06x', mt_rand(0, 1<<24 - 1));
```

A color is 8 bits for red, green, and blue, so we choose a random 24-bit number. Then we 0-pad it and print it as hex.

Answer (score 0):

```
$random_color = dechex(rand(0,255*255*255));
```